# How to center inside divs in a 1140px fluid responsive framework?

Tags: html, css

I'm using cssgrid.net which is a 12col 1140px responsive fluid framework and I'm having trouble centering things.

My website has a "background-size: cover;" image and I have a logo that I want to center horizontally within the browser, even when it's resizing.

*This is the HTML I have:*

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="fourcol"></div>
    <div class="fourcol">
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fourcol last"></div>
</div>
```

*And the CSS:*

```
.logo {
        background: url(../images/logo_retina.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 175px 175px;
    }
```

*This is what the top portion of my site looks like:*
[image]

The logo starts in the second set of 4 columns like it should, but how do I make it centered within that set of 4 columns, even when resizing?

Please keep in mind coding is just a hobby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each `div.fourcol` has the same fixed width I think that `background: url(../images/logo_retina.png) no-repeat center middle;` should help. If they are floating one another with width set to auto then it will be problem as `div.row` may be wider than the cumulative width of `div.fourcol`.

Comment: Yeah, from what I understand, each column has the same width. I just need to center the logo within that middle div.fourcol. I tried your center middle approach with no results.

Comment: My mistake, this solution was accurate!